# Display php-cli output in columns

Tags: php

I want to output data with variable length in columns in a php-cli script

Example:

```
$pepole = Array(
  'Mirco Dellarovere' => 'Artista',
  'Nino Pepe' => 'Attore',
  'Zoe Yan' => 'Futurista',
  'Mino' => 'Elettricista'
);

foreach($pepole as $name => $work)
  {
  echo "$name\t$work\n";
  }
```

The output will be

```
Mirco Dellarovere       Artista
Nino Pepe       Attore
Zoe Yan Futurista
Mino    Elettricista
```

but i want it this way

```
Mirco Dellarovere       Artista
Nino Pepe               Attore
Zoe Yan                 Futurista
Mino                    Elettricista
```

how to?

:) thanks

Comment: You'd need to use enough tab characters to account for the widest possible text in each column. If nothing else, try outputting `\t\t\t` instead of just `\t`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can [pad](http://www.php.net/str_pad) `$name` to ensure a standard number of characters. Just ensure that the number of characters(20) is equal to or larger than the length of the longest name:

```
echo str_pad( $name, 20 ) . $work . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks George Cummins, I think your's is a good solution... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Tabs/pads are boring.

**Use sprintf with a predefined $mask.** You can specify column widths and alignment.

In example below 20 is the width of the first column. If you want to adjust alignment you can add a - or + to the column like "%-20s %s\n". There are many formatting options. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$mask = "%20s %s\n";
foreach($pepole as $name => $work)
{
  echo sprintf($mask, $name, $work);
}
```