# Print multidimensional associative array column ways in html table

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I am a beginner in PHP and I have a large amount of data in a multidimensional array

```
$result = 
array
    (
    array(
        array("name" => "Volvo", "price" => 2222, "model" =>18),
        array("name" => "Tata", "price" => 2222, "model" =>18),
        array("name" => "Asoka", "price" => 2222, "model" =>18),
        ),
    array(
        array("name" => "BMW", "price" => 2222, "model" =>17),
        array("name" => "Benz", "price" => 2222, "model" =>17),
        array("name" => "Maroti", "price" => 2222, "model" =>17),
        ),
    array(
        array("name" => "porse", "price" => 25648, "model" =>16),
        array("name" => "farari", "price" => 25486, "model" =>16),
        array("name" => "Volvo", "price" => 25422, "model" =>16),
        ),

    );
```

I iterate through the array with a foreach loop, and print the model row ways,

```
foreach($result as $k => $datas){
         echo $datas[$k]['model'].'-->';
            foreach($datas as $key => $data){
             //print_r($data);
                 echo $data['price'] ;
                 echo $data['name'].'-*-';
              }
              echo '<br>';
         }
```

and when I run this code, I receive the following output:

```
18-->2222Volvo-*-2222Tata-*-2222Asoka-*-
17-->2222BMW-*-2222Benz-*-2222Maroti-*-
16-->25648porse-*-25486farari-*-25422Volvo-*-
```

However, I am trying to print column ways this array in html table, in a similar fashion to below:

```
   18   -->     17   -->    16-->
2222-Volvo  2222-BMW      25648-porse
2222-Tata   2222-Benz     25486-farari
2222Asoka   2222-Maroti   25422-Volvo
```

Comment: Then the first thing to do is to output HTML rather than just bare data

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: what will be the consistency that all cars will be grouped in single array based on model value?

Comment: is it possible that one single array may have multiple model cars? line model 18 and 17 cars in one single array?

Comment: Just put your information in multiple div and use css to have your column (watch flexbox for example)

Comment: brother @VinayPatil , No chance in same model in one single array.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599361/display-php-cli-output-in-columns

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```php
<div style='display:flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;'>

<?php
foreach($result as $k => $datas){
    echo "<div style='display:flex; flex-direction: column;'>";
    echo  "<div>" . $datas[$k]['model'] . "--></div>";
    foreach($datas as $key => $data){
        //print_r($data);
        echo "<div>" . $data['price'] . "-" . $data['name'] . "</div>" ;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

</div>
```

The output is :

[image]

As you can see, the logic is pure HTML/CSS :

- First I wrap your data inside a **flex** container with direction as **row** and **wrap** so if you have a lot of element they will go in the next row.
- Now in your foreach, each element are wrapped inside an other **flex** div but with the direction as **column** : so each new div inside this one will be display under the previous one.
- All the div inside are simple div, now your turn to make some css to center text, add padding or whatever

Is it what you are looking hope ? If you have question about flexbox check this : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: brother @Mickaël Leger thank you, you save my another day, but when i put my value on table then again show in row ways.

Comment: if i want to show data in column ways, then table is bade idea for showing this?

Comment: Flexbox is more...flexible, I think. With a table, you need to know by advance how many row you will have, how many column and in your foreach you need to put all first element in the first row, then all the second element in the second row in the right column, etc. I think it's harder than just using flexbox